# Is there a way to adjusts the brightness of the monitor?

Tags: monitors, brightness

Using the softbuttons is annoying over time. I mean the real brightness of the backlight (Not X11 gamma). Which protocols are cabable of this? (DVI, HDMI, DP, guess VGA is not)

Comment: This may depend on your GPU and GPU driver. What graphic card do you have, and which driver (`ati`, `fglrx`, `nouveau`, `nvidia`, …)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually, all of these interfaces are capable of backlight control (and more), as long as both, graphics card and the monitor support the **Display Data Channel**.

DDC is based on I²C, so you have to install and load appropriate kernel modules to make it work.

```
# Debian
sudo apt-get install i2c-tools
sudo modprobe i2c-dev

# RHEL
sudo dnf install i2c-tools
```

After that, you have to find out which I²C bus is connected to the monitor using `sudo i2cdetect -l`.

```
# Example output for Intel graphics card
i2c-0   i2c         i915 gmbus dpc                      I2C adapter
i2c-1   i2c         i915 gmbus dpb                      I2C adapter
i2c-2   i2c         i915 gmbus dpd                      I2C adapter
i2c-3   i2c         DPDDC-B                             I2C adapter
i2c-4   i2c         DPDDC-C                             I2C adapter

# Example output for AMD graphics card
i2c-0   i2c         Radeon i2c bit bus 0x90             I2C adapter
i2c-1   i2c         Radeon i2c bit bus 0x91             I2C adapter
i2c-2   i2c         Radeon i2c bit bus 0x92             I2C adapter
i2c-3   i2c         Radeon i2c bit bus 0x93             I2C adapter
i2c-4   i2c         Radeon i2c bit bus 0x94             I2C adapter
i2c-5   i2c         Radeon i2c bit bus 0x95             I2C adapter
i2c-6   i2c         card0-eDP-1                         I2C adapter
i2c-7   i2c         card0-VGA-1                         I2C adapter
```

In **Intel** case, the right bus is one of DPDDCs (*Display Port DDC*), depending which on port are you using. In my case both, HDMI and DP are displayed as DP.

In **AMD** case, the bus is called card0-*interface*-*n*.

If there are no interfaces listed, then your card/driver doesn't not support DDC in standard way.

Now we have to probe, whether monitor supports DDC and does it allow to set brightness this way. First, install `ddccontrol`:

```
# Debian
sudo apt-get install ddccontrol

# RHEL
sudo dnf install ddccontrol
```

Then, list get list of supported DDC parameters using it. This example assumes your DDC interface is bound to i2c-3 bus.

```
# sudo ddccontrol dev:/dev/i2c-3 
ddccontrol version 0.4.2
Copyright 2004-2005 Oleg I. Vdovikin (oleg@cs.msu.su)
Copyright 2004-2006 Nicolas Boichat (nicolas@boichat.ch)
This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You may redistribute copies of this program under the terms of the GNU General Public License.

Reading EDID and initializing DDC/CI at bus dev:/dev/i2c-3...
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/usr/share/ddccontrol-db/monitor/DELA0A2.xml"
Document not parsed successfully.
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/usr/share/ddccontrol-db/monitor/DELlcd.xml"
Document not parsed successfully.

EDID readings:
    Plug and Play ID: DELA0A2 [VESA standard monitor]
    Input type: Digital

= VESA standard monitor
> Color settings
    > Brightness and Contrast
        > id=brightness, name=Brightness, address=0x10, delay=-1ms, type=0
          supported, value=45, maximum=100
        > id=contrast, name=Contrast, address=0x12, delay=-1ms, type=0
          supported, value=75, maximum=100
--- [snip] ---
```

That's it, if everything goes right, brightness value should report exactly the same brightness as set in monitor. You might now set 50% brightness using this command (replace 0x10 with address of brightness value found above):

```
sudo ddccontrol dev:/dev/i2c-3 -r 0x10 -w 50
```

Comment: Absolutely cool thank you. Does this somehow integrate with gnome? Just because this is much more time-consuming than moving my fingers to the monitor. Still this is gorgeous, finally I can script my brightness.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I've been also looking for brightness solution for GNOME after I moved from laptop to a PC. It looks like GNOME uses X11 backlight control, which in turn uses Linux' backlight class devices, and there's no DDC ↔ Linux backlight driver.

Comment: You can use `gddccontrol`, a GTK UI for `ddccontrol`, but first you'd have to chown/chmod your I²C bus or write an udev rule to do it automatically.

Answer (score 15):

Building on @M132's answer, `ddccontrol` appears unmaintained and hasn't added configurations for any new monitors since 2006.

Fortunately, there is a newer tool: [ddcutil](http://www.ddcutil.com/), that is much more robust and actively developed.  After installing one of the [prebuilt packages](http://www.ddcutil.com/#installing-ddcutil-from-prebuilt-packages) or building from source, it can be used to query and set brightness (among myriad other settings):

```
# ddcutil capabilities | grep Brightness
Feature: 10 (Brightness)
# ddcutil getvcp 10
VCP code 0x10 (Brightness                    ): current value =    60, max value =   100
# ddcutil setvcp 10 70
```

Comment: or `ddcutil capabilities | grep Luminosity`

Comment: [Ddccontrol](https://github.com/ddccontrol/ddccontrol) got some good deal of updates in the last couple of years

Comment: It does not detect my second monitor.

Answer (score 7):

The [DDC/CI kernel module](https://gitlab.com/ddcci-driver-linux/ddcci-driver-linux) includes a `ddcci-backlight` module which can integrate most DDC/CI-capable monitors into the kernel’s backlight system (`/sys/class/backlight`). This allows any tool which can use the latter to drive the backlight on a DDC/CI monitor; for example, using the built-in controls on the GNOME desktop:

[image: Top-right of a GNOME desktop, showing the sound volume and screen brightness controls]

The kernel module is available in Debian (since Debian 9) and derivative distributions:

```
sudo apt install ddcci-dkms
```

Comment: That's just awesome. A kind of example of deeper hardware integration in Linux that many distros, unfortunately, lack. Just done packaging `kmod` for `ddci` kernel modules and really enjoying the brightness slider allowing to control it without any third party apps :) Thanks for mentioning it!

Comment: Just too bad gnome only shows one monitor max. That's a pity for folks like me using an external monitor on their docking station.

Answer (score 5):

There's `xbacklight` – "adjust backlight brightness using RandR extension".

However, it fails with my HDMI monitor, so I fall back to using software modification:

```
xrandr --output HDMI2 --brightness 0.7
```

Comment: Its 2015 display brightness should be controllable. http://ddccontrol.sourceforge.net/ looks like an answer but the software is abandoned by the authors.

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r Well, my HDMI monitor is not a 2015 model. Is there a problem with `xbacklight`?

Comment: It does not work for me. I use a dell u2414h.

Comment: Well, that's a 2013 model. ;-)  Seriously, my best guess is that it remains unsupported, and that software brightness (still distinct from Gamma) is the best you get: `xrandr --output HDMI --brightness 0.7`

Comment: `xbacklight` will work with laptops and other devices that use ACPI-based backlight control. For desktop monitors, the most widely supported solution is to use DDC and `ddccontrol`.